# variable and string concatenation in powershell

Tags: powershell, concatenation

I have below a piece of code.

```
ForEach($line in $lines){
Try
{
    $file = "C:\brivo\" + $line
    $ftpuri = "ftp://administrator:Hello123@172.16.1.54/divyesh/" + $line
    $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftpuri)
    $webclient.DownloadFile($uri,$file)
}
Catch [Exception]
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception | format-list -force
}
}
```

For the details of $lines when I run

```
$lines.GetType()
$lines
```

it is displaying like below.

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                           
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                           
True     True     Collection`1                             System.Object                                                      
Divyeshwewetwe.json
```

**$file = "C:\brivo$($line)"** line generating error every time I run this code with different options. like

```
$file = ("C:\brivo\" + $line)
```

and

```
$file = "C:\brivo\" + $line
```

it is giving me the below error every time.

```
System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request. ---> 
System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in
path.
```

When I give a static file name static then it is working fine like below.

```
$file = "C:\brivo\123.json"
```

Comment: What's in `$line`?

Comment: it is an array of file names. I have updated the code.

Comment: That still does not explain what is in `$line`.

Comment: it is the file name. and its name is Divyeshwewetwe.json

Comment: The problem is most likely that there are characters in the value of ```$line``` that are not valid if ftp uris. Add something like ```write-host “ftp uri = ‘$ftpuri’”``` and show us the output.

Comment: Or maybe your *real* password has invalid chars in it. Try the uri *without* authentication details and see if that gives the same error or a different “access denied”-type error…

Comment: it is giving this output, ftp uri = ‘ftp://administrator:Hello123@172.16.1.54/divyesh/Divyeshwewetwe.json’

Comment: Make a `$lines` variable that contains a value that triggers the "Illegal characters in path." error. Include that value in your question above. Everything else is a waste of time.

Comment: I have added value of $lines

Comment: Your output *doesnt* have ```ftp://``` at the start of the value - can you confirm if that’s exactly what you see on screen? And if so, check your code sample in this question matches the code you’re running locally - they contradict each other.

Comment: It is just file name. full path is generated from $file = "C:\brivo\" + $line
    $ftpuri = "ftp://administrator:Hello123@172.16.1.54/divyesh/" + $line

Comment: and i am getting error on $file = "C:\brivo\" + $line peace of code.

Comment: Show us how you obtained `$lines`. Is that a collection you read from a text file where filenames are listed one on each separate line, does it come from importing a CSV (with or without headers), something hardcoded but not shown in the code you posted or what?? It looks like you are reading a CSV, so you get an array of **objects** in variable `$lines` which is **not** the string array you take it for.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from my comment, I think your collection `$lines` is definitively **not** a string array, but an array of **objects** instead.
(`` Collection`1 `` means it is a [Generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/) collection of one or more of the types that they store or use)

You probably got that from importing a CSV file, something like

```
"FileName", "SomeOtherStuff"
"Divyeshwewetwe.json", "nothing here" 
"123.json", ""
```

Of course, you would have different column headers and the number of columns will also differ from this small example.

The key here is that you want to iterate over the **values** in just the one column, here called `FileName`

Try

<sup>I changed variable `$lines` into `$data` and iterating variable `$line` into `$item` as I find that more appropriate when iterating objects from a collection of objects.</sup>

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'X:\YourInputFile.csv'
foreach($item in $data){
    try {
        $file = Join-Path -Path 'C:\brivo' -ChildPath $item.FileName  # only the string value column FileName
        $ftpuri = "ftp://administrator:Hello123@172.16.1.54/divyesh/{0}" -f $item.FileName
        $webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
        $webclient.DownloadFile($ftpuri,$file)
        # dispose of the current $webclient
        $webclient.Dispose()
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host $_.Exception.Message
    }
}
```